# Tikz takes forever to compile when imported into main file

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling

I used `TikzEdt` in order to generate some figures to use in my thesis. However, when I included the source code by **copy-pasting/\input** in the main document `under a figure environment` my document took forever to compile without any errors and yielded a corrupted PDFoutput file after I cancel the compilation.

As far as I am concerned, I have all the necessary packages in the preamble and I have generated a minimal working example after inspecting the exported code from `TikzEdt`.

The non-compiling file is huge so the driving file is [here](https://pastebin.com/g46zxqa9), the [class file](https://pastebin.com/GC5TsseT) is a modified book class and the included [macros](https://pastebin.com/rJSjvJjP) are basic.

Furthermore `TikzEdt` complains that the following line with the message: "*Couldn't parse code. NoViableAltException in line 16 at position 44. Is some \end{} command missing?*". A compiling MWE is [here](https://pastebin.com/9KZbpdu5).

> \draw[<->, thick] (-1,0)++({\ang+90}:1) --++ (\ang:{2*cos(\ang)});

**EDIT** 
The issue is resolved and the problem was my usage of `\ang` which is an internal macro defined in the package `siunitx`. TikzEdt parser still complains, yet I do not know if it is a real problem.

A screenshot from the issue in `TikzEdt` is below. The error message is displayed in **red lines**. 
[image]

Comment: You want your example to produce the error but, if I've understood you correctly, the code you've posted will compile fine. Is that correct? Also, I'm confused about what you are doing with TkzEdt when it gives you the parsing error. I thought you exported the code from there? Are you saying it can't compile it either? If we need the other example, post it here instead of or as well as the existing one.

Comment: @cfr Both **MWEs** and TikzEdt compile and output a valid PDF. But TikzEdt complains, and I exported the code from there. I have a huge main thesis file with a big preamble and this is the file which does not compile.

Comment: @cfr After going through the preamble commenting out each comment to see if they are the culprit, I managed to make a minimal example with the same preamble as in the large document. This file compiled after commenting out `\siunitx` package which is pretty surprising and it also switched to compatibility mode as evident from: **Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package does not work correctly(caption) in compatibility mode. \begin{document}**.

Comment: But you say in the question that the MWE does NOT compile. Now you say it does, which means that the problem is in code we don't have. We need an example which produces the error. All that is wrong with this one is a missing `\begin{document}`. It compiles fine in either preview or non-preview mode.

Comment: Which error do you get from TeX when you compile? I don't have TkzEdt to compare. I can produce AN error by adding `xparse` but I don't know whether it is the right error.

Comment: @cfr I updated the question, hope it is much more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need a `\begin{document}`, obviously, but it otherwise works fine converted to a regular document with the picture in a `figure`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm,color}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,math}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \center
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzmath{\ang = 45;};
    \begin{scope}[thick,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{latex}}}
      ]
      \filldraw[red] (-1,0) circle (2pt)
      node[anchor=east, font = \footnotesize] at (-1,-0.2) {$\mathrm{E_0}$};
      \draw[dashed, red] (-1,0) --++({\ang+90}:1);
      \filldraw[green] (1,0) circle (2pt)
      node[anchor=west, font = \footnotesize] at (1,-0.2) {$\mathrm{E_0}$};
      \draw[postaction={decorate}, red] (-1,0) --++ (\ang:2);
      \draw[postaction={decorate}, green] (1,0) --++ (\ang:2);
      \draw[<->, thick] (-1, -0.2) -- (1, -0.2);
      \draw[dashed, green] (1,0) --++ ({\ang+90}:2.5);
      \draw[<->, thick] (-1,0)++({\ang+90}:1) --++ (\ang:{2*cos(\ang)});
      %       \draw[<->, thick] (-1,0)++({\ang+90}:1) --++ (\ang:{2*cos(\ang) });
      \node[anchor=north, font = \footnotesize]  at  (0, -0.2) {d=$\lambda/2$};
    \end{scope}
    \draw[blue, thick, dash pattern= on 25 off 7 on 50 off 7 on 10] (-2,0) -- (2, 0);
    \node[anchor=west, font = \footnotesize, blue] at (1.5,-0.05) {z}; node[near start, auto] {true}
    \draw[thick,blue,->] ([shift=(0:1)]1,0) arc (0:\ang:1);
    %   \draw[thick,blue,->] (2,0)  arc (0:\ang:1);
    \draw (1,0)++({\ang/2}:1.2) node[rotate=\ang, anchor=base, blue, font=\normalsize]{$\theta$};
    \draw ({\ang+90}:1.3) node[rotate=\ang, anchor=base, black, font=\normalsize]{$d\cos\theta$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Picture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: figure]

Possibly I don't understand the question.

## EDIT

Adding `siunitx` produces AN error, though whether it is YOUR error, I don't know. Specifically `xparse` complains that `\ang` is not expandable. This is because the current code invokes `\ang`, which is no longer an unassigned macro name. So it is trying to expand `\ang` to its definition, but can't. (And, if it could, the results would not be good either.)

The solution is to use a new name such as `\myangle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb,bm}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,math}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \center
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzmath{\myangle = 45;};
    \begin{scope}[thick,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{latex}}}
      ]
      \filldraw[red] (-1,0) circle (2pt)
      node[anchor=east, font = \footnotesize] at (-1,-0.2) {$\mathrm{E_0}$};
      \draw[dashed, red] (-1,0) --++({\myangle+90}:1);
      \filldraw[green] (1,0) circle (2pt)
      node[anchor=west, font = \footnotesize] at (1,-0.2) {$\mathrm{E_0}$};
      \draw[postaction={decorate}, red] (-1,0) --++ (\myangle:2);
      \draw[postaction={decorate}, green] (1,0) --++ (\myangle:2);
      \draw[<->, thick] (-1, -0.2) -- (1, -0.2);
      \draw[dashed, green] (1,0) --++ ({\myangle+90}:2.5);
      \draw[<->, thick] (-1,0)++({\myangle+90}:1) --++ (\myangle:{2*cos(\myangle)});
      %       \draw[<->, thick] (-1,0)++({\myangle+90}:1) --++ (\myangle:{2*cos(\myangle) });
      \node[anchor=north, font = \footnotesize]  at  (0, -0.2) {d=$\lambda/2$};
    \end{scope}
    \draw[blue, thick, dash pattern= on 25 off 7 on 50 off 7 on 10] (-2,0) -- (2, 0);
    \node[anchor=west, font = \footnotesize, blue] at (1.5,-0.05) {z}; node[near start, auto] {true}
    \draw[thick,blue,->] ([shift=(0:1)]1,0) arc (0:\myangle:1);
    %   \draw[thick,blue,->] (2,0)  arc (0:\myangle:1);
    \draw (1,0)++({\myangle/2}:1.2) node[rotate=\myangle, anchor=base, blue, font=\normalsize]{$\theta$};
    \draw ({\myangle+90}:1.3) node[rotate=\myangle, anchor=base, black, font=\normalsize]{$d\cos\theta$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Picture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

compiles to the output shown above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think this is some sort of package clash issue as I explained in the comment under my answer. It seems to conflict with `siunitx` package.

Comment: Then you need to edit your question to provide code which really does not compile, else we can't possibly know what the problem might be.

Comment: You are right, it did not occur to me it was a `package clash issue` in the first place. I think I need to upload my class file and the main file together with the defined macros.

Comment: @Vesnog Please see my edit above first. You haven't said what error you get, so I don't know whether the error I got is your error, but presumably you will know whether it is or not. At any rate, this is A problem with the code, even if not the only one.

Comment: I am now trying to change that `\ang` variable and see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: The compilation issue in the document with the same preamble is resolved now trying it with the main document. Thanks for your assistance. I am still interested in how did you isolated the problem and found the source, though. Did you inspect the logs?

Comment: @Vesnog When TeX stopped due to the compilation error, it told me what the error was. That is, it told me that `xparse` said that `\ang` was not expandable. That had to be because `siunitx` defines `\ang`, since the only thing I changed was adding `siunitx`. QED No need to read the logs.

Comment: Okay I understood mine tried to compile for an indefinite time. I do not know why this behavior is different.

Comment: @Vesnog Yes, those are often harder. Sometimes you can figure it out by looking at the console when you kill the process. But not always and all you learn is usually *where* and not *what* is wrong.

Comment: I ran the same command in TexStudio with showing all the standard output and it did not halt. In command line although the processor continued working a very explanatory message is displayed. I do not know why there is such a difference with the **same command**.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! siunitx error: "invalid-number"
!
! Invalid numerical input '='.
!
! See the siunitx documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................

l.112 \tikzmath{\ang = 45;}
                           ;

Comment: @Vesnog I always switch to the command line when trouble-shooting. It is easier than fighting the editor, I find. ;)